# Initializing auth2 for signing in users in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to manage a users authentication in a React App.

I keep getting errors related to dealing with `getAuthInstance()` and trying to `signOut()` a user.

First I am trying t load the `gapi.auth2`

```
    componentDidMount() {
        var auth2;
        var googleUser;

        var appStart = function() {
            gapi.load('auth2', initSigninV2);
        }

        var initSigninV2 = function() {
            auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
                client_id: '817677528939-dss5sreclldv1inb26tb3tueac98d24r.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                scope: 'profile email'
            });
        }

        googleUser = auth2.currentUser.get()
        console.log(googleUser)
```

When the page loads, I have everything under `componentDidMount()`

However, `auth2` keeps returning as undefined and thus getting an error. What am I doing wrong?

Why isn't auth2 initializing properly?

Comment: Because you're doing `auth2.currentUser.get()` before `auth2 = gapi.auth2.init` is executed.

Comment: ahhh ok.... I see. It doesn't wait for it to finish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues which I can see:

1. You're calling `auth2.currentUser.get()` before `auth2 = gapi.auth2.init` is executed
2. You're never calling the function `appStart`

This should get it working for you

```
function componentDidMount() {
    var auth2;
    var googleUser;

    var appStart = function () {
        gapi.load('auth2', initSigninV2);
    }

    var initSigninV2 = function () {
        auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
            client_id: '817677528939-dss5sreclldv1inb26tb3tueac98d24r.apps.googleus‌​ercontent.com',
            scope: 'profile email'
        }).then((auth2) => {
            googleUser = auth2.currentUser.get();

            console.log(googleUser)
        })
    }

    appStart();
}
```

Comment: var initSigninV2 = function() {
            auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
                client_id: '817677528939-dss5sreclldv1inb26tb3tueac98d24r.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                scope: 'profile email'
            })
            .then((auth2) => {googleUser = auth2.currentUser.get()})
            .then((googleUser) => {console.log(googleUser)})

        }

Comment: then I run `appStart()` but I never see anything get printed

Comment: @MorganAllen Edited, get rid of the second `.then()`

Comment: thank you! I keep forgetting that JS is non blocking

Comment: another question, bit of a tangent. If I want to re-use the gapi.auth2 in another function elsewhere, do I have to reinitialize all over again? for example in another function at the "same level" as `componentDidMount()`

Comment: I mean, you could just move the deceleration outside of the function, but you'd have to make sure it's defined first

Comment: ok, but in JS since it's defined inside one function doesn't make it globally accessible?

Comment: @MorganAllen Nope, that would make it local, take a look at [Scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)